# Display form via Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony

### Edit

Many questions on SO are about form submission via Ajax ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002489/symfony2-form-with-csrf-passed-through-jquery-ajax) is very popular) but not about how to display a form through an ajax call.

My question is about the part in bold: **the user asks for a form -> ajaxCall -> displayForm** -> user submit the form -> send the form to the controller -> validates form -> send response to the user (errors or not).

---

### The question

The ajax call being a POST, `$request->isMethod('POST')` always returns `true` when doing an ajax call. Therefore if a new form is being requested through an ajax call, it will always be validated. I have enclosed the code below, the form is displayed ok, but the following error message is displayed in the form:

> The CSRF token is invalid.

The problem is that the form is being validated during the ajax call requestion the form in the controller.

On a side note, submitting the form works well, and validation works well.

Does anyone know how to display a form via Ajax without having the blank new form being validated?

### My code so far:

```php
/**
 * Display the message as well as the form to reply to that message
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function viewMessageAction(Request $request)
{
    //Forbid every request but jQuery's XHR
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        return new Response('', 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
    }

    //Retrieve the message from the request
    $messageId = $request->request->get('messageId');
    $message = $this->getMessageManager->getMessage($messageId);

    //Creates the form to reply to the message
    $form = $this->container->get('reply_form.factory')->create($message);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //...
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
        }
    }

    $answer =$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('AcmeMessageBundle:Message:message.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'message' => $message
    ));

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $response->setContent(json_encode($answer));
    return $response;

}
```

### EDIT: jQuery part:

```java
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        var myPath = ;//...

        function getMessage(messageId){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  myPath,
                data: "messageId="+messageId,
                success: function(returnData){
                    $('#message').html(returnData);
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ajax call doesnt always need to be POST. It could be GET, PUT or DELETE . So when you are making ajax call to get the form make it a GET request.

If you are using jquery here is how you do that

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost/proj/url",
   type:'GET'
})
```

If you are using Using XHR, you can specify the type in the open function

```
xhr.open( 'GET', URL)
```

PS: It will be a good idea to use [JMS Serializer Service](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) for serialization instead of json_encode

Comment: Many thanks @Sethunath, I have updated my question with my jQuery code. Unfortunately, I am using the POST method to ask which form I need from the controller.

Comment: If you need to use POST , you need to pass some parameters too to distinguish from form submit. If you can make it GET , it should work right away

Comment: That sounds smart! So I could pass a parameter like `isFormRequest` and if this is true I do not perform the validation? Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. But it is always better if you could make the request GET

Comment: I see... but I definitely need to send a query to the controller..otherwise I don't get the right form :)

Comment: Quick question: is there a reason why you prefer JMS Serializer Service. Is it a better practice? Thanks @Sethunath, you've helped me very much!

Comment: Yes JMS Serializer is a well written Object oriented library for serialization. And it works perfectly with the Doctrine Entities

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interessted in the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle), since it add a lot of comfort working with ajax and Symfony2 routes in general.

Comment: Thanks @byf-ferdy. I am already using FOSJsRoutingBundle, it's a very good recommendation.